# How do you turn on iPhone LED with Xamarin?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am looking to use Xamarin to develop a simple all that turns on the LED on the back of iPhone. How exactly can I achieve this?

I imagine there is an API that I can use for this, but have not been able to locate examples of the LED/flashlight in Xamarin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code to turn on the flashlight:

```
var device = AVCaptureDevice.DefaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
if (device == null)
{
    return;
}

NSError error = null;
device.LockForConfiguration(out error);
if (error != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(error);
    device.UnlockForConfiguration();
    return;
}
else
{
    if (device.TorchMode != AVCaptureTorchMode.On)
    {
        device.TorchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.On;
    }
    device.UnlockForConfiguration();
}
```

Use `AVCaptureTorchMode.Off` to turn off the flashlight

Comment: Hi Giorgi. Thank you for the code snippet. What namespace reference do I need to make in order for 'AVCaptureDevice' to resolve. Ive had inserted your snippet and it claims the name does not exists.

Comment: hmm..looks like its in AVCaptureDevice.DefaultDeviceWithMediaType..validating.

Comment: got it. had to add references to 
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using AVFoundation;
using System.Diagnostics;